# Convert datetime in xslt

Tags: datetime, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

How should i convert datetime in xslt if i get the datetime in GMT in below format

```
<date>2017-02-05T10:40:00+04:00</date>

output : 2017-02-05 14:40:00.000
```

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: "*i get the datetime in GMT*" You do **not** get the datetime in GMT. You get the datetime in a timezone that's 4 hours **ahead** of UTC. In order to get the corresponding UTC datetime, you need to **subtract** 4 hours, not add them.  -- In any case, the answer depends on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. If it's XSLT 1.0, tell us which processor, so that we know which extension functions can be used, if any.

Comment: am using xslt 2.0. you are correct need to add/subtract based on the conversion factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(., xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to convert:

```
<date>2017-02-05T10:40:00+04:00</date>
```

into:

```
<date>2017-02-05T06:40:00Z</date>
```

Comment: i was able to do it when i just passed one element but not able to do it when passing the whole xml. am new to xslt parsing please help

Comment: Your updated question makes no sense. You have a named template, but you don't show how it's called (if at all). In any case, it has nothing to do with the original question. I suggest you roll back your edit and post a new question with your current problem.

Comment: sorry if i am not clear i call the template in   <xsl:template match="/">. sorry i did not post my complete xslt. i need to convert the date and build the rows

Comment: I still think you should post this as new question. But in general, you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(checkintime, xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="checkintime"/>` - and likewise for `chekouttime`.

Comment: as you said i have edited this back to original question and posted a new question. can you please take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097300/how-to-convert-datetime-while-transforming-xml-via-xslt